# Apple mail has ghost SMTP accounts. It does not use them, nor can I edit them. Any idea how to fix that?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, gmail

I have been having problems on Apple Mail on my work Mac.

I had setup everything on my personal Mac, and the settings were carried over via iCloud, no problem. I can receive mail for both Gmail and iCloud accounts. But I cannot send **ANY** emails. SMTP servers definitely have a problem with them. Some symptoms:

1. Whenever I try to change the Outgoing Mail Account, it just doesnt stay this way

[image]

2. List item I keep seeing ghost accounts. So for example:

[image: Account dropdown]

But in reality:

[image: Accounts from edit menu]

3. Connection Doctor doesnt should anything relating to SMTP. It just keeps spinning the wheel

[image: Connection Doctor]

Comment: What SMTP settings are you using? Some ISPs restrict SMTP access due to spam, so make sure you're using either port 465 with SSL or 587 with TLS, and authenticating with your Gmail/G Suite account

Comment: I'm letting it define its settings. But when I tried to do it manually, I chose 587 indeed.

I'm not sure if the problem is in the server settings though, because even if they were right, they just dont stay selected. And I stills see the "ghost" accounts